# Why isn't this a right expression for FM?

Tags: communication, modulation

Like AM that can be represented as:

$$\bigl(A_c+Km(t)\bigr)cos\bigl(2\pi f_ct\bigr)$$

Here, simply the amplitude is being varied by a sinusoid.

Therefore similarly, why can't FM be written as:

$$A_ccos\Bigl(2\pi\bigl(f_c+Km(t)\bigr)t\Bigr)$$

Obviously the constants are such that the frequency doesn't go negative.

Isn't the above equation intuitively correct? The frequency is being varied by a sinusoid again.

Comment: That looks like phase modulation.

Comment: are you kidding me? This doesn't looks like anything

Comment: Why do you think that this is not a correct expression for FM?

Comment: @Chu: Phase modulation would be \$A_c \cos(2\pi f_c t + Km(t))\$.

Comment: Because the derived expression for FM in every source looks like the expression of phase modulation you have mentioned. Both FM and PM have been treated equally. Also, the expression I have mentioned doesn't plot well on the graph. Therefore it's wrong but I wonder why.

Comment: Remember that phase is simply the integral with respect to time of frequency. Your expression looks reasonable to me, with the proviso that usually you see these expressions with the 2Pi taken out and using angular frequency instead of Hz, but it is just a constant.

Comment: The thing is in the derived expression, there is no such term with m(t)*t that is present here.

Answer (score 1):

An FM-modulated signal looks like
$$A_c \cos\left(\varphi\left(t\right)\right)$$

At time \$t\$, its frequency is
$${1 \over 2 \pi}{\mathrm{d}\varphi \over \mathrm{d}t}$$

And you want it to be
$$f_c + K m(t)$$

So you must have
$$\varphi(t) = \varphi_0 + \int_0^t f_c + K m(u) \mathrm{d}u
             = \varphi_0 + f_c t + K \int_0^t m(u) \mathrm{d}u$$

Hence, the expression for an FM-modulated signal is
$$A_c \cos\left(\varphi_0 + f_c t + K \int_0^t m(u) \mathrm{d}u\right)$$